# Fourier transform calculation never stops

Tags: performance-tuning, fourier-analysis

I'm trying to calculate a Fourier transform and plot it, however the calculation is running for several hours now. I suspect that there is a mistake in my script. Or am I just not patient enough? Is there any shortcut, like evaluating the FT numerically? When I encounter this problem with **Integrate**, I usually still get reasonable and quick results using **NIntegrate**. Is there anything like that for Fourier transforms as well?

```
beta2 = -7.63;
fs = 39 ;

spectrumdisp[f_, fs_, beta2_, L_] := 
Exp[-I*beta2*f^2*L/2]*Exp[-((f/(2*fs))^2)^3];

Plot[Abs[FourierTransform[spectrumdisp[f, fs, beta2, 1], f, t]], {t, 1, 100}]
```

However, i'm not sure if the FourierTransform alone works this way at all. Already this command does not finish calculating:

```
FourierTransform[spectrumdisp[f, fs, beta2, 100], f, t]
```

I would be very glad if someone could help me with these problems.

Comment: First problem: Replace `==` by `=`: `beta2 = -7.63; fs = 39;`.

Comment: Try in addition to @Henriks comment `Plot[Abs[FourierTransform[spectrumdisp[f, fs, beta2, 1], f, t]] // 
  Evaluate, {t, 1, 100}]`

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, thanks, i edited it above.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann this makes it actually so much faster. Now, it takes only a few seconds. Can you explain to me, when and how often the fourier transform is evaluated now?

Comment: @Mechanix Quite often there is some kind of  conflict inside Plot-function with the plot-variable `t` . ` Evaluate` forces the evaluation of the plotfunction before plotting.